# mongoose Look for an exact word in a phrase

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

As of now when I search for a text, it is searching through each character using this code:

```
model.find( { title: { $regex: /word/i } } )
```

but the result comes like 'word', 'word123' or '333word3' and I want only the titles that contain 'word' word in it. eg: 'this is a word'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put [\b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes) allows you to perform a “whole words only” search using a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`

```
Model.find({
  title: {
    $regex: "\\bword\\b"
  }
})

//or

Model.find({
    title: /\bword\b/
})
```

If you want ignore such cases: `foo-word`, `bar:word`, `word-buz` use this:

```
Model.find({
  title: {
    $regex: "\\b(^|\\s|[^\\W])word(\\s|[^\\W]|$)\\b"
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I really appreciate your help, the regex looks complicated to re-write or edit as needed.can you please suggest the documentation or a source to understand it?

Comment: @slim Sure. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), [here](https://regex101.com/), [here](https://regexone.com/) and [here](https://www.princeton.edu/~mlovett/reference/Regular-Expressions.pdf) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You're [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) expression dosen't exclude those options you said

You need to either:

1. Change up the regex to something like `/ word /i` if you want to force a space around the word, mind you if combinations like word-word2 are relevant you'll have to account for those as well in the regex you form.
2. Use Mongo's [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) option, for that you'll have to build a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) on that field. Keep in mind that Mongo stems words when it indexes the text field meaning a word like `cars` would become `car` meaning this might not be the best option for you if an exact match is a requirement.